# How can I delete any items between two marker elements in an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to find a way to remove any elements in an array that fall between two "markers", but there are a few quirks. To give a proper spec, the function I'm making is supposed to do this:

> Remove any elements from the earliest *start marker* `S` to the earliest *end marker* `E` after the `S`, or the final element if there is none. Repeat this until there are no `S`s left. Remove any remaining `E`s.

For example, if I had an array containing the following:

This is my current code:

```
# if the starting token is `1` and the ending one is `2`:
while clearing.include? 1
    from = clearing.index(1)
    to = clearing[from..-1].index(2) + from
    clearing.slice!(from..to)
end
clearing.delete(2)
```

Which, when run with `clearing` set to:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", 1, "g", "h", "i", "j", 1, "k", 2, "l", 2, 2, "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", 1, "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", 1, "y", "z"]
```

properly returns

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s"]
```

<sup>[Online test](http://ideone.com/KijfJV)</sup>

It works, but it's ugly, and I'm fairly sure there's a more idiomatic way to do it. I can't find it, though, or think of it, so I'm asking here: Is my code the only (sane) way to do what I'm trying to?

---

This is, unfortunately, a severe case of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248725) -- the specific task I'm trying to accomplish is removing comments from a string. I could do this with a fairly simple regex (`/#.*?$/m`) if I had the input string, but because it's a class assignment, I have to delete from anything starting with `#` to the `:newline` token in an array of them. Please don't suggest "This is weird, why not try solving the overall problem a different way" -- I know it's weird. I wish I could.

Comment: These are two minor suggestions. Firstly, when giving an example, it's best to assign a variable to each input object. Here, `clearing = ["a",...]`. That way, readers can just cut and paste when testing code and, more importantly, can refer to the variable in comments and answers without having to define it. (Yes, you did say that array was `clearing`.) Secondly, whenever possible, format your code so that it can be read without the need for horizontal scrolling. Here you could have broken the array `clearing` into two lines.

Comment: @CarySwoveland At the time, I was rushed. Feel free to edit the question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Also, I provided an online test that people are free to use.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, I think any solution is going to be as elegant as yours. The only thing I can think of is that you could make it faster by iterating over each character only once:

```
i = 0
loop do
  break if i >= clearing.length
  break if clearing[i] == 1
  i += 1
end

loop do
  break if i >= clearing.length
  val = clearing.delete(i)
  break if val == 2
end
```

Which is definitely *less* elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's fairly obscure ["flip-flop"](https://matousek.wordpress.com/2008/12/06/ruby-flip-flop-operator/) operator could be used here. I'm not recommending that it be used, just sayin'.

```
clearing.reject { |e| (e==1..e==2) ? true : false }.reject { |e| e==2 }
  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s"]
```

The first block returns `false` until `1` is detected. It then returns `true` for the `1` and continues to return `true` until `2` is detected. It returns `true` for the `2`, but then returns `false` until the next (if any) `1` is detected, and so on. Hence, the name "flip-flop". The example often given for the flip-flop operator is reading sections of a file that are delimited with start/end markers.

It may seem that `(e==1..e==2) ? true : false` could be simplified to `(e==1..e==2)`, but that is not the case, as the latter expression is treated as a normal range. Flip-flops must have a conditional form.

Replace both `reject`s with `reject!` if `clearing` is to be changed in place.

Comment: Hey, in that article you linked, it says that this feature is discouraged. As cool as it is, I'd rather be sticking with things that aren't.

Comment: I don't think there is universal agreement about that, but as long as it is used Rubiests need to know that it exists and how it works.

Comment: If you can find a more recent article which says it's encouraged, I'd recommend putting that in instead. Until then, while it's a cool trick, this isn't a good answer, because it's suggesting the use of a discouraged feature.